# Change Biztalk SSO Key?

Tags: biztalk, single-sign-on

I've discovered I need to change a key name in our Biztalk SSO database,
obviously, changing a value on the fly is ok with the SSO Settings Editor, but is there any shortcut way to change the key name?  I've looked at tools available with no joy.

Any info appreciated.

Comment: The MMC snap-in doesn't let you change the key name?

Comment: Not that I can see, although Ive not had too much experience with it so I could be wrong

Comment: Can you export it to XML, change the key name, and reimport?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft actually has a separate SSO Configuration Application MMC Snap-In available from their website that allows you to edit the name of the key (among other things). You can download the installer from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=94e07de1-1d33-4245-b430-9216979cd587.

Once you've installed the MMC snap-in, run it, expand the appropriate application, right-click on the key-value setting you want to edit, and choose Properties. That will enable you to edit the key name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.........Export current settings in to XML, Delete the application settings from SSO Database and then reimport modified settings............